# How mapped types works with base types?

Tags: typescript

I can't understand why in the situation below `type T0` is a string and not an object with keys "toString" , "slice" "split" ... and why `type T1` is an object with the key type `string` while we know that keyof any is a `string | symbol | number`?

```
type MappedType<T> = {
[K in keyof T]: T;
}

type T0 = MappedType<string>;
type T1 = MappedType<any>;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An authoritative answer for `T0` can be found in the [pull request](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/12447) that implemented "homomorphic [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types)", or mapped types of the form `{[K in keyof T]: ...}` where `T` is a generic type parameter.  (Note that it was originally called "isomorphic" instead of "homomorphic", but it's the same thing.)

The normal use case for such a mapped type is when `T` is some object type; in this cases, the mapping preserves the key names from `T` as well as their "read-onliness" and "optionality" modifiers.  (It is possible to override these modifiers by explicitly setting them in the mapped type.)

So what happens when `T` is a primitive type like `string`?  The pull request says "we simply produce that primitive type".  This turns out to be very useful, especially in cases where you are using mapped types recursively.  A type like

```
type DeepPartial<T> = { [K in keyof T]?: DeepPartial<T[K]> }
```

will walk down through a nested object type and make each subproperty optional... *and leave primitives alone*:

```
declare const ab: DeepPartial<{ a: { b: string } }>;
const str = ab.a!.b!; // string
```

This is almost always what people want.  If such a type kept on recursing downward into all properties of wrapped primitives like `length` and `toUpperCase`, you'd end up with a largely useless type.   And then the only way to get the "normal" version would be to use [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#conditional-types) to terminate the descent instead of mapping primitives:

```
type DeepPartial2<T> = 
  { [K in keyof T]?: T[K] extends object ? DeepPartial2<T[K]> : T[K] }
```

which is less convenient (and wasn't possible until TS2.8 introduced conditional types anyway).

In some sense, people usually want to preserve "the same general shape" for things mapped homomorphically, but what "the same general shape" means isn't always obvious.  Object types stay object types.  Primitives stay primitives.  Originally, arrays were treated as regular object types, producing a nearly useless type which transformed array methods into something unrecognizable.  This was not pleasant for anyone, which is why [TypeScript 3.1 changed it](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays) so that mapped array types are still array types, and mapped tuple types are still tuple types.

---

That leaves us with `T1`, where a homomorphic mapping over the properties of `any` yields an indexable type.

The previously linked pull request doesn't go into it, but the implementer explained his reasoning in a [comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30082#issuecomment-467079029) to a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30082) reporting this behavior as a bug:

> `keyof any` is `string | number | symbol`, so a mapped type applied to `any` yields the equivalent of `{ [x: string]: XXX }`.

Note that he says "the equivalent of".  `symbol` is automatically removed from mapped types, so `{[K in "a" | symbol]: string}` yields `{a: string}`.  You *are* allowed to have both `string` and `number` indices separately, so `{[K in string | number]: string}` is `{[k: string]: string; [k: number]: string}`.  But since numeric keys are considered string-valued in [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types) and [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Property_names), this is the same as `{[k: string]: string}`.  (If you care to read more about what happens to `string`, `number`, and `symbol` keys when mapped over, you can see [this documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-9.html#support-number-and-symbol-named-properties-with-keyof-and-mapped-types).)

Personally, I'm not 100% on board with `keyof any` being mapped to just a `string` index instead of both `string` and `number`, since `{[K in keyof T]: K}` would show a difference... but it's a minor point.

The important point is from the rest of the comment:

> You could argue that we should just yield `any` when a homomorphic mapped type is applied to `any`, but that would be less precise. For example `{ [K in keyof T]: number }` instantiated with `T` as `any` really ought to yield `{ [x: string]: number }` and not just `any`.

So there you go; `any` is treated like an object type with string-indexable keys so that mapping over it yields something reasonable.  And that comment is the closest I've seen to a canonical answer to this question.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBAsghmSATAKuCAeFA+KBeKAbwCgooBtAaSgEsA7KAawhAHsAzKFAXQC4uA3FGIBfYsVCQuABnywEyNJAwBnYACd6Ac2wCJ6LgEY58RBFToMcOiF3jJ0ACIQIYAApx1wGnAA2WXAJCCmp6JhYOLm4Afn5nVw8vH38UKm5cMWIkCABjX09oHNY6NSg4ACM4l3dPbz8MYLh+YMqoNU06LSgRbrsikuA2jTkKgDo4AEJR8omhAHo5oY6tewN4mqS-ACYAuWCqWgZmNk4eWK40qAgAD2AIOiQVKFZygCtcweiodcS63x3UpR0lB+IDuN0srl8upCsVShUtlUErVkjtGs0oK12tpur09P1Su0tiNyltxlMZvNFtjOqspAAtOQ-FH1ay2PT6KQAOVYAGUQABbcqsXx7EKHKAAIjgkqgAB82oLhb4+EscSI9AsoA4oDz+UKRXsmmrOpkdbyNNoAIIPLkAVyFEHUYoOYRpXQVdAd5Sdqvd3U1ACptQYLcsbUh7Y7nUFSGQKNd+O6-ZbOnp4wn+F7oynlnoeoG5sQgA)