# Why does a branded string/number type made DeepWriteable no longer extend string/number?

Tags: typescript, mapped-types

I have a `DeepWriteable` type and a branded number type `PositiveNumber`. `PositiveNumber` extends `number`, but `DeepWriteable<PositiveNumber>` does not. Same story for a branded string type. What's going on here?

```
type DeepWriteable<T> = { -readonly [P in keyof T]: DeepWriteable<T[P]> };
type PositiveNumber = number & { __brand: 'PositiveNumber' };
type NonEmptyString = string & { __brand: 'NonEmptyString' };

type test1 = PositiveNumber extends number ? true : false;
// TRUE
type test2 = DeepWriteable<PositiveNumber> extends number ? true : false;
// FALSE
type test3 = NonEmptyString extends string ? true : false;
// TRUE
type test4 = DeepWriteable<NonEmptyString> extends string ? true : false;
// FALSE
```

(BTW, I'm only asking about branded types because regular `number` and `string` don't seem to have this behavior)

```
type test5 = DeepWriteable<number> extends number ? true : false;
// TRUE
type test6 = DeepWriteable<string> extends string ? true : false;
// TRUE
```

I've resorted to just adding a check to `DeepWriteable` to not map over `number`s and `string`s which works fine, but I'm curious why it's necessary.

Is it because the `-readonly` transformation makes this a non-homomorphic mapped type? I think I can maybe see why this happens for `string`, because `length` is `readonly`. Is there a similar `readonly` property on `number`?

Comment: Any mapped type on a branded primitive will destroy the primitive (it's not just non-homomorphic mapped types); see [ms/TS#35992](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/35992).  Does that fully address your question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks! Combined with your answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62883000/20071103) question things are making more sense.

Comment: My apologies for asking a follow up, but one question this raises is whether primitives are exceptions to the structural typing principle? (b/c hovering over the result of DeepWriteable<PositiveNumber> shows all the methods of number, but is obviously not a true number anymore.)

Comment: Yes, you can think of most primitives as being nominal subtypes of their wrapper interfaces (that is, every `string` is a `String` but not vice versa).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) (even [homomorphic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59790508/2887218) ones) on a [branded primitive](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#can-i-make-a-type-alias-nominal) (a [primitive type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#the-primitives-string-number-and-boolean) which has been [intersected](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types) with an object-like type) will end up destroying the primitive type.

Homomorphic mapped types on regular, non-branded, primitives were special-cased in [microsoft/TypeScript#12447](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/12447) to return the primitive without alteration.

But for branded primitives you get the mapping over all the properties and apparent properties of the input type, which means `DeepWriteable<PositiveNumber>` will give you a result with all the `Number` interface properties as well as a `__brand` property.

As mentioned in [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/35992#issuecomment-572184086) on the related issue [microsoft/TypeScript#35992](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/35992):

> Branding a primitive with an object type is an at-your-own-risk endeavor. Basically you can do this as long as the type never goes through a simplifying transform ... That said, I'm describing the current behavior, not outlining any promises of future behavior. T... We do use some branding internally but don't file bugs against ourselves when we encounter weirdness

So it looks like the recommendation is to avoid doing too much type manipulation on branded primitives, or at least to test such manipulations thoroughly and tweak them to deal with any unexpected wrinkles that arise when the types do not compose as you might hope.